# SED: Append a line at the end of a range

Tags: bash, sed

I'm looking to add some lines before the end of a range in a file.

`sed '/BEGIN/,/END/ /$/i \ SOME TEXT TO ADD' /path/to/foo`

- Original file:

  `random text
  BEGIN
  foo
  bar
  END
  random text`
- Expected behavior after SED:

  `random text
  BEGIN
  foo
  bar
  SOME TEXT TO ADD
  END
  random text`

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Which version of sed, and how much do you hate the syntax of the `i` command?

Comment: sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2

If you have a solution for this, please share it.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/BEGIN/,/END/!b;/END/iSOME TEXT TO ADD' file
```

If there are lines not between `BEGIN` and `END` print as normal otherwise if the line contains `END` insert some text.

Comment: Do I read this command correctly by saying: "If you are between `BEGIN` and `END`, do not branch to the end of the commands, otherwise do"?

Comment: Yes, if you like you can surround the commands following the range with  braces but then you have to end the  insertion with a newline which means writing three separate lines , split the commands into two sets or using Bash something like: `sed $'/BEGIN/,/END/{/END/iSOME TEXT TO ADD\n}' file`

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just look for the end tag, and insert before:

```
sed '/END/ iSOME TEXT TO ADD' /path/to/foo
```

Otherwise you must use several lines:

```
sed '/BEGIN/,/END/ {
    /END/ iSOME TEXT TO ADD
    }' /path/to/foo
```

Comment: I can't use that. If I use END, it might match the wrong END. I need it in a specific range, because START is unique.